# How is the cast working there even the eclipse is not flagging an error

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, casting, threadpool

ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor)
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

when i was looking through the api docs the fixedThreadPool() returns an instance of executor service but here we are casting the fixedThreadPool() to ThreadPoolExecutor it is weird since the ThreadPoolExecutor implements executor service can anyone explain me how this cast works??

Answer (score 0):

TheadPoolExecutor is a subclass of ExecutorService interface.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

As you mentioned, fixedThreadPool() returns an instance of ExecutorService interface. The runtime object instance that is getting returned is TheadPoolExecutor. So your class casting is working.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run this code:

```
ExecutorService te = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
System.out.println(te.getClass());
```

Output:

```
class java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
```

As you can see the returned instance is [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). Here `ExecutorService` is an interface and `ThreadPoolExecutor` implements it.
You can cast from super type to sub type. So it is working.